# How to print unsorted dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dict in python;

```
d={}
d['b']='beta'
d['g']='gamma'
d['a']='alpha'
```

when i print the dict;

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print k
```

i get this;

```
a
b
g
```

it seems like python sorts the dict automatically! how can i get the original unsorted list?

Gath

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Dicts don't work like that](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> **CPython implementation detail**: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

You could use a list with 2-tuples instead:

```
d = [('b', 'beta'), ('g', 'gamma'), ('a', 'alpha')]
```

A similar but better solution is outlined in [Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928686/how-to-print-unsorted-dictionary-in-python/2929007#2929007).

Answer (score 11):

As has been mentioned, dicts don't order or unorder the items you put in. It's "magic" as to how it's ordered when you retrieve it. If you want to keep an order -sorted or not- you need to also bind a list or tuple.

This will give you the same dict result with a list that retains order:

```
greek = ['beta', 'gamma', 'alpha']
d = {}
for x in greek:
    d[x[0]] = x
```

Simply change [] to () if you have no need to change the original list/order.

Comment: I get the sorted result. What kind of python do you use

Comment: @Samuel, you mean that your dictionary prints out in apparently sorted order? Because that's totally by "accident" - it's all left up to the underlying Python implementation. It might print out the same order you put it in, it might not.

Comment: @Wayne Werner, Yes, I want the unsorted print out. I need to construct a `YAML` file from a `dict`. I always get the sorted content.

Comment: @Samuel, you probably should ask a question - please ensure it's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a dictionary. Or use the Python 2.7/3.1 `OrderedDict` type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no order in dictionaries to speak of, there is no *original unsorted list*.

Comment: As Marcelo Cantos mentions, newer versions of Python provide OrderedDict, which preserves insertion order.

Comment: @John: as OP mentions he's using built-in `dict`

Answer (score 1):

No, python does not sort dict, it would be too expensive. The order of `items()` is arbitrary. From python docs:

> CPython implementation detail: Keys
>   and values are listed in an arbitrary
>   order which is non-random, varies
>   across Python implementations, and
>   depends on the dictionary’s history of
>   insertions and deletions.