# Not getting the same result when inverting a dictionary twice

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to invert a simple dictionary like:

```
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}
```

I'm using this function:

```
def invert(d):
    return dict([(x,y) for y,x in d.iteritems()])
```

Now when I invert my dictionary, everything works out fine. When I invert it twice however, I get:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

which is not in the same order as the dictionary I started with. Is there a problem with my invert function? Sorry I'm kinda new to python, but thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a good video on dictionaries : http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147

Answer (score 3):

That is correct, dictionaries are unordered in python

from [another so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928686/how-to-print-unsorted-dictionary-in-python) answer:

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary). A pair of braces creates an empty dictionary: {}. Placing
>   a comma-separated list of key:value pairs within the braces adds
>   initial key:value pairs to the dictionary; this is also the way
>   dictionaries are written on output.

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are unsorted by design.

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead if you really need this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this code:

```
d = {
    'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 
    'c' : 3, 'd' : 4
}

def invert(d):
    return dict([(x,y) for y,x in d.iteritems()])

print d

d = invert(d)

print d

d = invert(d)

print d
```

This is the output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

As you can see, it technically *is* the same dictionary, but when you declare it, it is unordered.